# Cumulative sum on specific column with groupby on last n_days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I'm trying to perform a rolling sum on a column for the `last_n` rows and cast to a new column in the dataframe, with grouping by a different column. So here's a sample of the type of dataframe I have:

```
id.   a.   b.    c.    date.    
01    0    abc   def   1/22/20  
01    2    abc   def   1/23/20  
01    1    abc   def   1/24/20  
01    1    abc   def   1/25/20  
02    4    abc   def   1/22/20  
02    5    abc   def   1/23/20  
02    5    abc   def   1/24/20  
02    0    abc   def   1/25/20  
03    1    abc   def   1/22/20  
03    0    abc   def   1/23/20  
03    2    abc   def   1/24/20  
03    2    abc   def   1/25/20  
.
.
.
```

These are arbitrary values, but let's say I want to do a rolling sum for the past 2(example) days on `column=a.` for each `id`. Output should look like this:

If past `n` days don't exist, just add `0` to the cumulative sum.

```
id.   a.   b.    c.    date.    rolling_2_a
01    0    abc   def   1/22/20  0
01    2    abc   def   1/23/20  2
01    1    abc   def   1/24/20  3
01    1    abc   def   1/25/20  2
02    4    abc   def   1/22/20  4
02    5    abc   def   1/23/20  9
02    5    abc   def   1/24/20  10
02    0    abc   def   1/25/20  5
03    1    abc   def   1/22/20  1
03    0    abc   def   1/23/20  1
03    2    abc   def   1/24/20  2
03    2    abc   def   1/25/20  4

.
.
.
```

I know how to do a sum based on id but here with the date element + the `last_n` requirement, I'm not sure if `pandas` has that capability.

For the sake of this, let's assume the `date` column may also not be sorted, but examples for both would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICCU

```
#Coerce date to datetime
  df['date.']=pd.to_datetime(df['date.'])

#Set date as index
  df.set_index('date.', inplace=True)

#Group by id 

 df['rolling_2_a']=df.groupby(df['id.'])['a.'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('2D').sum()).fillna(0)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: window must be an integer` on `.rolling('2D')` but changing that to `.rolling(2)` seems to work. Could you explain what is going on? Also in this scenario, is it taking the current day into account or summing `n-2`?

Comment: From documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html   '2' will give you Rolling sum with a window length of 2, min_periods defaults to the window length. 2D will give you minimum periods. My solution should work. Ensure you set date to datetime and set it as index after coercing it to datetime. Follow then with groupby

Comment: Ah yes I thought my column was already in datetime, that was the issue. Thanks! I don't understand the difference between the window length and the '2D' minimum periods though, any input is appreciated